# truncate all tables in Postgres except for the ones provided in a list

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, truncate

I want to truncate the whole database while maintaining the sequence identity. I came up with something like this:

```sql
WITH tables_to_be_truncated AS (
SELECT table_name
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE'
    AND table_schema='public'
    AND table_name NOT IN ('admins', 'admin_roles')
)
TRUNCATE TABLE (SELECT table_name FROM tables_to_be_truncated) CONTINUE IDENTITY RESTRICT;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TRUNCATE"
LINE 9: TRUNCATE TABLE (SELECT table_name FROM tables_to_be_truncated...
```

I do have the permissions to truncate the tables and when I run for a single table like `TRUNCATE TABLE access_tokens` it works fine.

I also tried with this

```sql
TRUNCATE TABLE (SELECT string_agg(table_name, ', ') FROM tables_to_be_truncated) CONTINUE IDENTITY RESTRICT
```

which didn't work as well.

From what I see in other posts, people are doing it with functions. I didn't want to go down this path honestly but if this is the only way...

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for this. `TRUNCATE` syntax supports only a static list of table names, not a query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a function for that. An [`anonymous code block`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) will do:

```
DO $$
DECLARE row RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR row IN SELECT table_name
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE'
    AND table_schema='public'
    AND table_name NOT IN ('admins', 'admin_roles') 
  LOOP 
    EXECUTE format('TRUNCATE TABLE %I CONTINUE IDENTITY RESTRICT;',row.table_name);
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Other than that I don't think you'll be able to run dynamic queries with pure SQL.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=988e990cb675547c70e31676c7771d60)

Comment: amazing! that is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, just did, couldn't accept earlier because of the SO cooldown :)

Comment: @LuizE. no problem.. happy coding :)